# How to refresh hidden form field using jquery and multiplicate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i´ve got a very dumb question ... 
i´ve got a form in wordpress where first of all you have to select a date 
if date 1 is selected you only have got to fill in how many seats (price 30) you want to reserve
if you select date 2 (dropdown) you get a second input field where you also could reserve a cup of tea (17.50) ...

on the bottom of the page has to be the total sum - so far it´s working ... but if i select date 1 again, and go back to date 2 the sum still remains on 17.50 …

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function einblenden(){
        var land   = document.getElementById('tea-date').selectedIndex;
        if(land == 1) {
document.getElementById('tea').style.display = "block";   
document.getElementById('tea-sum').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('tea-input').value = ""; }
            else {
document.getElementById('tea').style.display = "none";  
document.getElementById('tea-sum').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('tea-input').value = "";
}        }
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery("#tea-seat").bind("keyup change", function(e){ var val1 = jQuery("#tea-seat").val(); var val2 = 30; jQuery("#tea-sum").text(val1*val2); }); 
jQuery("#tea-input").bind("keyup change", function(e){ var val3 = jQuery("#tea-input").val(); var val4 = 17.50; jQuery("#tea-cup-sum").text(val3*val4); }); 
});
// ]]></script>
```

```html
<p>Date*     
        <select name="tea-date" id="tea-date" onchange="einblenden();">
            <option value="1. Oct 2016">1. Oct 2016</option>
            <option value="2. Oct 2016">2. Oct 2016</option>
        </select>
       
<p>Seats*<br />
[number* tea-seats min:1 max:50 default:1 id:tea-seat]</p>

        <div id="tea" style="display: none;">
<p>reserve tea<br>( 17.50 $/cup)<br />
[number cup-tea min:0 max:50 default:0 id:tea-input] Cup/s</p>
        </div>

<p><strong>Total Price of seats: <span id="tea-sum"></span> Money</strong></p>
        <div id="tea-sum" style="display: none;">
<p><strong>Total Price of Tea Cups: <span id="tea-cup-sum"></span> Money</strong></p>
</div>
<p>[submit "submit text"]</p>
```

is there someone who could help me? :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: is there also a possibility to sum up the whole total of both? -> like Tea Seats : 60 Moneys Tea Cups: 17.50 Moneys Total: 77.50 Moneys